# Occlude foreign PK from HTML value attribute Django Crispy Forms

Tags: django, postgresql, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

When rendering a choice form field of `ModelB` with django crispy forms, the foreign key id of `modelA` is available in the HTML attributes of the choice objects. My understanding is that the primary key id of `modelA` is sensitive and should not be shown to the users.

```
<select name="modelB" class="select form-select is-invalid" id="id_modelA"> 
<option value="FK1" selected="">Choice 1</option> 
<option value="FK2">Choice 2</option> 
...
<option value="FK5">Choice 5</option> </select>
```

Ideally, I could use `modelA.uuid` as a proxy for the true `modelA.id` in the html attributes but crispy forms doesn't want to allow this.

```
<select name="modelB" class="select form-select is-invalid" uuid="uuid_modelA"> 
<option value="uuid1" selected="">Choice 1</option> 
<option value="uuid2">Choice 2</option> 
...
<option value="uuid5">Choice 5</option> 
</select>
```

Model A:

```
class modelA(models.Model):
    user_instance = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid_lib.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=False)
```

Model B:

```
class modelB(models.Model):
    user_instance = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    modelA_instance = models.ForeignKey(modelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='modelB')
    uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid_lib.uuid4, unique=True, editable=False, primary_key=False)
```

I've tried overriding the choices widget using a construction like below but crispy rejects any user input because the `modelA.uuid` that is pass into the HTML choice `value` is not a foreign key that matched the queryset:

```
modelA_queryset = modelA.objects.filter(user_instance=self.user)
self.fields['modelA'].queryset = modelA_queryset
self.fields['modelA'].widget.choices = [(modelA.uuid, modelA.__str__) for modelA in modelA_queryset]
```

Using this construction allows me to get uuid into the choice value but Crispy gives a generic client-side form validation error and prevents submission.

`Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.`

It seems like there should be some way to do this but I haven't been able to find anything. If the form was able to post, it wouldn't be too hard to hand the `uuid` -> `id` conversion in the `clean` and `save` methods of the form.